# How to align itext columntext and make width 100%

Tags: itext, hebrew

I need to add text in Hebrew at the bottom of the last page to an existing PDF. I managed to do that however, I need the text to be aligned at the center. The pdftable has one column only. Also I want the column to be 100% width.

This is my code:

```
Dim LastPage As Integer = pdfRd.NumberOfPages 'The page number
Dim cb As iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfContentByte = Nothing
Dim ct = New ColumnText(cb)
Dim rows As Single() = {500} 'create column sizes 
Dim nTbl As PdfPTable = New PdfPTable(1) 'number of columns in our case 1
Dim cellFont As iTextSharp.text.Font = New iTextSharp.text.Font(BaseFont, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.RED)

nTbl.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL

nTbl.WidthPercentage = 100 'Table size is set to 100% of the page
nTbl.LockedWidth = True   
nTbl.SetTotalWidth(rows) ' Set the column widths on table  

nTbl.DefaultCell.Border = 0
nTbl.AddCell(New iTextSharp.text.Phrase(MsgOnClosing, cellFont))
nTbl.SetExtendLastRow(1, 1)
' nTbl.HorizontalAlignment = iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_LEFT 'align table
ct.Alignment = iTextSharp.text.Element.ALIGN_CENTER
'ct.SetSimpleColumn(70, 36, iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Width - 36, iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Height - 300)

nTbl.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 0, 20, stamp.GetOverContent(LastPage)) 'coords x=300,y=300                    
ct.Go()
```

Answer (score 1):

There is something strange going on in your code.

You create a `ColumnText` object, but you're not doing anything with it. Remove all references to `ct` and your code produce exactly the same PDF as before:

```
Dim LastPage As Integer = pdfRd.NumberOfPages 'The page number
Dim rows As Single() = {500} 'create column sizes 
Dim nTbl As PdfPTable = New PdfPTable(1) 'number of columns in our case 1
Dim cellFont As iTextSharp.text.Font = New iTextSharp.text.Font(BaseFont, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.RED)
nTbl.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL
nTbl.WidthPercentage = 100 'Table size is set to 100% of the page
nTbl.LockedWidth = True   
nTbl.SetTotalWidth(rows) ' Set the column widths on table  
nTbl.DefaultCell.Border = 0
nTbl.AddCell(New iTextSharp.text.Phrase(MsgOnClosing, cellFont))
nTbl.SetExtendLastRow(1, 1)
nTbl.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 0, 20, stamp.GetOverContent(LastPage)) 'coords x=300,y=300
```

If I look at the code listed about, I see some more strange things:

```
nTbl.WidthPercentage = 100 'Table size is set to 100% of the page
nTbl.LockedWidth = True   
nTbl.SetTotalWidth(rows) ' Set the column widths on table
```

This doesn't make sense. The width of a `PdfPTable` can be expressed either as a percentage (using `WidthPercentage`), or as an absolute width (using `setTotalWidth`). The value of `LockedWidth` will determine whether the percentage is used (`false`), or the absolute width (`true`). In your case, you choose to use the absolute width, so setting the width percentage doesn't make sense.

It also doesn't make sense because you are adding the table using the `WriteSelectedRows()` method. When using `WriteSelectedRows`, you *must* use the absolute width. In your case, I would define that width like this:

```
nTbl.SetTotalWidth(iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Width - 72)
```

But make sure that you have the coordinates right:

```
nTbl.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 36, 20, stamp.GetOverContent(LastPage))
```

You should also throw away the line where you define the `rows` variable. And why did you add `nTbl.SetExtendLastRow(1, 1)`? That shouldn't have any effect in combination with the `WriteSelectedRows()` approach.

**Alternative #1:**

There is also another way to achieve what you want, you could indeed use `ColumnText`, but in that case you have to add the `PdfPTable` to the column. Note that what you did with the variable `cb` didn't make sense either, I have thrown away that line:

```
Dim LastPage As Integer = pdfRd.NumberOfPages 'The page number
Dim ct = New ColumnText(stamp.GetOverContent(LastPage))
Dim nTbl As PdfPTable = New PdfPTable(1) 'number of columns in our case 1
Dim cellFont As iTextSharp.text.Font = New iTextSharp.text.Font(BaseFont, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.RED)
nTbl.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL
nTbl.WidthPercentage = 100 'Table size is set to 100% of the page
nTbl.DefaultCell.Border = 0
nTbl.AddCell(New iTextSharp.text.Phrase(MsgOnClosing, cellFont))
ct.SetSimpleColumn(36, 0, iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Width - 72, 36)
ct.Go()
```

Again, I had to throw away some lines. For instance: if you set the width of the table to 100%, why would would you need to set the alignment of the column?

**Alternative #2:**

The main problem with your code is that it is convoluted. Why do you use a `PdfPtable` if all you want it to add some Hebrew text?

The correct direction comes out of the box if you use iText 7 and the pdfCalligraph add-on instead of the old iText 5. However, if you insist on using iText 5, you can simple add a Hebrew text to a `ColumnText` like this:

```
Dim LastPage As Integer = pdfRd.NumberOfPages 'The page number
Dim ct = New ColumnText(stamp.GetOverContent(LastPage))
ct.SetSimpleColumn(36, 0, iTextSharp.text.PageSize.A4.Width - 72, 36)
ct.RunDirection = PdfWriter.RUN_DIRECTION_RTL
Dim myFont As iTextSharp.text.Font = New iTextSharp.text.Font(BaseFont, 10, iTextSharp.text.Font.NORMAL, iTextSharp.text.BaseColor.RED)
ct.AddElement(New iTextSharp.text.Paragraph(MsgOnClosing, cellFont))
ct.Go()
```

Why would you spend 17 obscure lines of code when you can achieve the same result in 7 lines that are crystal clear?

Comment: Thanks so much Bruno. With SetSimpleColumn the hard coded values- will the result always be the same since the pdf size is dynamic? Will the location of the new content not be affected?

Comment: Obviously you have to adapt the hard coded values. Currently, the code assumes that `(0, 0)` ([the origin of the coordinate system](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/where-origin-xy-pdf-page)) is the coordinate of the lower-left corner, and that the width of each page is the width of an A4 page. You will need to [get the page dimensions of each page](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-get-pdf-page-width-and-height) if the page size in unpredictable. See [How to position text relative to page?](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-position-text-relative-page)

Comment: I am trying to fix the position so that the new text will be at the bottom of the page but I still don't understand in SetSimpleColumn where to set the value so that the text will appear at the bottom of the page. I looked at your links.